# Basic binary operation on set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, binary-operations

Hey please help me answer this question:
Given a set $A$ with at least 2 elements which on it the binary operation * is defined in that manner:

for every $a,b\in A,  a*b=b$.

Check if the binary operation * is commutative, associative and idempotent.

Comment: We've learned so far elementary-set theory and very basic binary operations, I'm not yet familiar with axioms so please avoid using it in your answer.

Comment: It should be easy to see it’s not commutative

Comment: for me its still difficult since I struggle with wrapping my head around it

Comment: " I struggle with wrapping my head around it ".  That is why they gave you these exercises.  But if we do them for you, will it help you wrap your head around it?

Comment: @GEdgar yes it will since I missed an important class and now Im behind the rest of the class, so now I have to learn it by myself, this is the most simple example from the tasks which I choose because I want to understand this simple stuff before I move any further and an example solution would be very useful for me to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer emphasizing substitutions

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, No I understand it much better!

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Say $A$ has at least two different elements, name them $5$ and $2$. Then $$5*2 = 2\ne 5 = 2*5$$
so it is not commutative.

Since we have also:
$$a*(b*c) = a*c = c$$ and $$(a*b)*c = b*c=c$$

we see it is associative. Also we have $b*b = b$ so ...

Comment: Im sorry could you explain what:

a∗(b∗c)=a∗c=c∧(a∗b)∗c=b∗c=c

means?

Comment: The confusing part is to write $\wedge$ instead of the word "and".  Aqua was very lazy, avoiding 2 letters, but making it confusing.

Comment: Hello! This is a nitpick, but I think your answer would benefit from using the fact that $A$ has at least two elements to pick distinct $a, b$ from $A$ rather than using $2$ and $5$ in your counterexample (how do you know $2*5$ is even defined? let alone a counterexample to a property about elements of $A$)

Comment: Thank you @GEdgar  but you are fast on words, wedge is 2 letters more than and :)

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen thanks for exactnes

Comment: I have another simple question:
how did you came to the assumption that:

a∗(b∗c)=a∗c=c

where c came from?

Comment: Can you tell me when is an operation associative?

Comment: @Aqua when you can group the numbers in any combination?

Comment: Write a formula for that!

Comment: (2+1)+1=4=(1+1)+2

Comment: Well, that is if operation is comutative. In general it si not correct. Go and look on wiki.

Comment: so we must have three elements to proof it?